# The purpose to define open set in metric space

Tags: real-analysis

I understand that an open set is a set whose points are all interior points so all the points won't have relation with outside. However, if we define the metric function $d: X\rightarrow\mathbb{Z^+}$ ,$\mathbb{Z^+}$ the positive integers, so all the set in $X$ are open set according to the definition. So I want to know what is the purpose for us to define open set?

Comment: A metric function is usually $X × X → ℝ_{≥0}$, do you mean for your metric to take values only in $ℤ^+$ (or maybe rather $ℤ_{≥ 0}$, since $d(x,x) = 0$ for all $x ∈ X$)?

Comment: @k.stm I mean the metric just takes value for positive integer

Comment: So you’ll end up with a [discrete metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_metric). But if you don’t give any context, it is hard to say what the purpose of such a metric is. Why are you even considering discrete metrics?

Comment: @k.stm For example we can define the step between two points on the chessboard as metric.

Comment: @k.stm so it seems that the open set doesn't make sense in that kind of metric.

Answer (score 2):

If we have a metric space $X$, and all distances are positive integers, then the points are isolated from each other.  The purpose of looking at open sets is to make this statement rigorous.

For example, if we write a topological space $X=U\cup V$, where $U\cap V$, and $U$ and $V$ are both open, then we have written $X$ as the union of two disconnected pieces.  It is impossible to do this with, for example, the plane (we say that the plane is *connected*).

Back to your metric space with integer distances: we can write $X = \cup_{x\in X}\{x\}$, where each set in the union is open.  So the space itself is as disconnected as possible (we say that it is *discrete*).  This agrees with our intuition about such a space, that there is lots of room between the points.

Comment: So what is the purpose for us to define an open set in general?

Comment: @89085731 There are many, many purposes, but the idea of _continuity_ is at the heart of most of them.  As an example: a space may be more or less disconnected.  A discrete space is the most extreme example of a disconnected space, but we might also want to say that a space can be split into exactly two parts (e.g. the set of points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $x\neq 0$).  Or maybe we'd like to say rigorously that the sphere and the plane are not the same object, even though they both look 2-dimensional up close.  We can do this with the notion of _compactness_, which requires open sets.